# Web scraping a table and can't locate the table

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am scraping this website: https://www.misoenergy.org/markets-and-operations/market-reports/market-report-archives/#nt=%2FMarketReportType%3ABids%2FMarketReportName%3AArchived%20Cleared%20Bids%20%20(zip)&t=10&p=0&s=FileName&sd=desc

And try to download all the zip files from the table. However, I can not locate the table from the 'soup'. It returns nothing.

```
req = Request(
    'https://www.misoenergy.org/markets-and-operations/market-reports/market-report-archives/#nt=%2FMarketReportType%3ABids%2FMarketReportName%3AArchived%20Cleared%20Bids%20%20(zip)&t=10&p=0&s=FileName&sd=desc',
     headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
page = urlopen(req).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
tables = soup.find('div', class_='table table-bordered docnav-metadata dataTable no-footer')
```

Comment: The content gets loaded dynamically. Try using `selenium` or `requests_html` or something to fetch them.

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you be more explicit please?

Comment: If you disable javascript in your browser and reload the page, you wont see that tabular content. BeautifulSoup can't catch such content.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Why not just use firebug or chrome developer tools to check the ajax call and emulate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as stated, you need something like selenium to load the page as it's dynamic. You'll also need to let it wait to load to get the table.

NOTE: I used time.sleep() for the wait, but I have read that is not the best solution. The suggestion is to use `WebDriverWait` but I'm still in the pr0cess of understanding how that would work, so will update this once I play around. In the meantime, this should get you started.

```
import bs4 
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.misoenergy.org/markets-and-operations/market-reports/market-report-archives/#nt=%2FMarketReportType%3ABids%2FMarketReportName%3AArchived%20Cleared%20Bids%20%20(zip)&t=10&p=0&s=FileName&sd=desc')


time.sleep(5)    

html = driver.page_source
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

tables = soup.findAll('table', {'class':'table table-bordered docnav-metadata dataTable no-footer'})
```

This worked for me with `WebDriverWait`:

```
import bs4 
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.misoenergy.org/markets-and-operations/market-reports/market-report-archives/#nt=%2FMarketReportType%3ABids%2FMarketReportName%3AArchived%20Cleared%20Bids%20%20(zip)&t=10&p=0&s=FileName&sd=desc')

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table.table-bordered.docnav-metadata.dataTable.no-footer")))

html = driver.page_source
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

tables = soup.findAll('table', {'class':'table table-bordered docnav-metadata dataTable no-footer'})
```

Answer (score 1):

To fetch the tabular content from that webpage using ***[`Requests-HTML`](https://html.python-requests.org/)*** library, you can try the following script:

```
import requests_html

link = "https://www.misoenergy.org/markets-and-operations/market-reports/market-report-archives/#nt=%2FMarketReportType%3ABids%2FMarketReportName%3AArchived%20Cleared%20Bids%20%20(zip)&t=10&p=0&s=FileName&sd=desc"

with requests_html.HTMLSession() as session:
    r = session.get(link)
    r.html.render(sleep=5,timeout=8)
    for items in r.html.find("table.dataTable tr.desktop-row"):
        data = [item.text for item in items.find("td")]
        print(data)
```

Comment: Finally someone using requests_html 